# What's the meaning of (0,x) and (1,x) in this code?

Tags: python-3.x

This code is used to sort a big_list but put the small_list in the beginning of the big_list. 
I don't understand how the argument 'x' is passed to the def helper and what's the meaning of return (0,x) and (1,x) here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def sort_list(value, group):
    def helper(x):
        if x in group:
            return (0,x)
        return (1,x)
    value.sort(key=helper)
big_list = [8,3,1,2,5,4,7,6]
small_list = [2,3,5,7]
sort_list(big_list, small_list)
print(big_list)
[2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(0,x)` is a two-member tuple. The key insight is that tuples sort by first element, disambiguating by second element, then next.... and only being equal when each member is equal. Thus, for example,

```
(0, 0) < (0, 1) < (0, 2) < (1, 0) < (1, 1) < (1, 2)
```

Thus, `helper` as the sort key will sort any elements in `group` before any elements outside `group`; but then sort by value inside each part. This accounts for `2, 3, 5, 7` being ordered, `1, 4, 6, 8` being ordered, and the former coming before the latter.

Comment: Hi Amadan, thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate a little bit about this part? 
"if x in group:". In this code, we didn't pass any argument to helper function, how x can be checked if it exists in group?

Comment: We never even call `helper`: [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) does. It passes an argument (`x`) into `helper` ("`key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element"). `group` is in the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) of `helper`, and can thus be accessed.